# How does rescue_action in Rails3 work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to implement this

```
class SecurityTransgression < StandardError; end

 def create
   raise SecurityTransgression unless ...
 end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def rescue_action(e)
  case e
    when SecurityTransgression
      head :forbidden
    end
  end
end
```

from the [this blogpost](http://pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/272-access-control-permissions-in-rails).

The problem is it does not work. I dont see a forbidden page but standard Rails error page "SecurityViolation in MyController#action". I digged that some rescue_action methods works only in the production mode. I tried that and it is the same. No change.

**My question**: is there any good documentation of the rescue_action method (and others)? Does this work under Rails 3.0? Because it seems this is some old

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at rescue_from at the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Does rescue_from supersede rescue_action in Rails3?

Comment: Rescue_from is the way to go in Rails3, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The rescue_action method is normally called internally with the @_env hash being passed as a parameter. The method is expecting the Exception instance to exist within the "action_dispatch.rescue.exception" key.

If you must use the rescue_action method directly, you can do the following:-

```
@_env[ "action_dispatch.rescue.exception" ] = exception
rescue_action( @_env )
```

or even more simple:-

```
rescue_action( { "action_dispatch.rescue.exception" => exception } )
```